# How to add endpoint mapping to Azure IaaS VMs (new resource manager) via Portal?

Tags: azure, azureportal

Current guidelines to add an Endpoint mapping are way too complicated compared to the classic VMs model.

Is this the only way now to simply map a public port to an internal port?
https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-pt/documentation/articles/load-balancer-arm-powershell/

Comment: I answered this on ServerFault, [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/737717/unable-to-configure-port-mapping-for-azure-availability-set-in-the-new-portal/737796#737796) - it shows how to add endpoints via the portal, for ARM-based VM's.

Comment: But still not able to add a mapping (different public port).

Comment: BTW: "ARM-based VMs" is also a very bad acronim from Microsoft Azure. Too lame considering the market trends for ARM CPUs http://perspectives.mvdirona.com/2015/10/arm-server-market/

Comment: Posted feedback here:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/11500695-add-endpoint-in-the-new-resource-manager-based-vm

Answer (score 0):

It's not the ultimate way to configure endpoints on IaaS VMs that use the ARM model. Actually - please note that it may change at the discretion of MS - each VM you create using the new portal will come by default with a network security group (NSG) with the same name as the VM, that you'll be able to search for later in the portal.

Then, you'll be able to edit those NSG to make them compliant with your requirements.